# I can't plot a certain solution

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

`DSolve[{x''[ u] == -(1/ 2)*(2*1*(\[CapitalTheta] (u + a) - \[CapitalTheta] (u - a)))*x[u]}, {x[u]}, {u}];`
x[u] /. {{x[u] ->
C[1] Cos[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] u Sqrt[[CapitalTheta]]] +
C[2] Sin[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] u Sqrt[[CapitalTheta]]]}}

**Can't plot the above solution I have to plot in three regions u<=-a, -a<=u<=a, u>=a. Please help**

Comment: Please make a bit more effort on formating your code properly. If you don't know how to, check e.g. this post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/1871

Answer (score 0):

Note the derivative is written "x''" not "x^[Prime][Prime]", although they look similar. The first has character code: 39, your prime has character code: 8242.

Then you can define a result function like the following example:

```
 fun[u_] = x[u] /. DSolve[{x''[u] == -(1/2)*(2*1*(\[CapitalTheta] (u + a) - \[CapitalTheta] (u - a)))*x[u]}, {x[u]}, u][[1]]
```

To plot you must give values to your constants as well as the integration constants. For an example, I set all to: 1

```
fun[u_] = 
 x[u] /. DSolve[{x''[u] == -(1/2)*(2*1*(\[CapitalTheta] (u + a) - \[CapitalTheta] (u - a)))*x[u]}, {x[u]}, u][[1]] /. {a -> 1, \[CapitalTheta] -> 1, C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}
Plot[fun[u], {u, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: `x^\[Prime]\[Prime]` is probably a copy-paste issue. If one directly copy `x''` in `StandardForm` from a notebook to somewhere outside of notebook, it'll be like that. This is not hard to fix, when one paste it back to a notebook, just press Ctrl+Shift+N, then `^\[Prime]\[Prime]` will format correctly.

Comment: Thanks! .Understood .The solution that I’m getting how to plot it in piecewise function form?

Comment: It does not make sense to chnage an ordinary function to piecewise. If you want to plot from a to b: Plot[fun[x],{x,a,b}]